# How to make the powershell show history

Tags: powershell, user-interface, terminal, oh-my-posh

I have 3 'different' powershel versions, one came from the VSCode Extension, another one is the default and the preview version. Today I was opening some ps terminals, and when I open a terminal from vscode (right click over some folder) the pwsh that open up came with an awesome feature (or bug?) where the history of commands shows below my current line allowing me to see them like in this print

[image]

How can I keep this behavour? I mean probably this is a bug, but for me this is an awesome feature! I use ohmyposh as well...

The GPT told me that this History information came from the `Import-Module PSReadline` but of course I already knew it, but it commonly appears inline like a gray autocomplete but I prefer this 'combo-box' style. Can some expert help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `Get-PSReadLineOption` and check `PredictionViewStyle` option. Default is `InlineView`, but you can change it:
`Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView`